# SQL Server Export Blob Corrupts All Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob, ole

I am exporting blobs with this code:

```
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

DECLARE @outout_path varchar(50) = 'D:\blob',
        @i bigint,
        @init int,
        @data varbinary(max),
        @file_path varchar(max),
        @folder_path  varchar(max)

DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id int identity(1,1) , [FileName]  varchar(100), file_data varBinary(max) )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([FileName],file_data)
Select top 10 thefilename, file_data FROM  schm.table_with_blobs

SELECT @i = COUNT(1) FROM @Doctable

WHILE @i >= 1
BEGIN

    SELECT @data = [file_data],
           @file_path = @outout_path + '\'+ cast(id as varchar) + '\' + [FileName],
           @folder_path = @outout_path + '\'+ cast(id as varchar)
    FROM @Doctable
    WHERE id = @i

  EXEC [dbo].[CreateFolder]  @folder_path

  EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT;
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1; 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @data;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @file_path, 2;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @init;

  print 'Document Generated at - '+  @file_path  

SELECT @data = NULL,
       @init = NULL,
       @file_path = NULL,
       @folder_path = NULL;

SET @i -= 1;
END
```

All the files are exported as expected with the proper file format. However, all of the files are corrupted and cannot be opened, regardless of file format. What can I tweak to avoid this? Do I need to more explicitly call out the file type (available in `thefilename` field)?

Comment: Try verifying that `schm_table_with_blobs` actually contains the data you expect, by doing a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), file_data)` on a file type that should contain more-or-less readable data (`.txt` would be ideal, but `.pdf` can do in a pinch). Also, open the exported files with a text or hex editor to see if that matches what's in the database. This way you can narrow down if the problem is in the use of `ADODB.Stream` or the data itself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `.txt` look normal in the database and export properly (i.e. not corrupted). Other file types (e.g. PDF, Excel) are gibberish in the database...and the same gibberish when opening the exported file in Notepad.

Comment: Not sure whether that means the ADODB stream is the problem or not

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but was exporting with BCP rather than using ADODB.
I had to do two things :

- convert the varbinary to varchar or nvarchar
- make BCP export as
  RAW

This is the BCP solution I came up with:

```
Declare @patient int, @mincount int, @maxcount int,@filename varchar(200), @script varchar(2000),@fileid varchar(10)

Set @patient=2;
set @mincount=1;

Declare @mydocs as table
(filename varchar(255), filebody image, drank int, file_id int)
insert into @mydocs
Select taf.Attachment_File_Name, taf.Attachment_File_Body, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY taf.attachment_file_id) as drank, taf.Attachment_File_ID FROM [CNGSTT].[dbo].[tblAttachment] ta 
left join  [CNGSTT].[dbo].[tblAttachmentFile] taf 
on taf.Attachment_ID=ta.Attachment_ID where ta.Patient_ID=@patient

Set @maxcount=(select MAX(drank) from @mydocs)

WHILE @mincount<=@maxcount
BEGIN

Set @filename = (select fle.FileName from @mydocs fle where drank=@mincount)
Set @fileid =(select fle.File_id from @mydocs fle where drank=@mincount)

set @script = 'bcp "SELECT cast(cast(Attachment_File_Body as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) from [tblattachmentfile] fle where Attachment_File_ID='+@fileid+'" queryout D:\temp\' + @filename + ' -T -c -C RAW'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @script
Set @mincount=@mincount+1
END
```

Comment: thanks - I'll take a look at the BCP route. what are the pros/cons between BCP vs. ADODB?

Comment: mostly that unless you run it externally you have to execute via xp_cmdshell. It may be worth experimenting with the ADODB method and try pushing the varbinary in as a varchar... happy experimenting!

Comment: yep, I tried forcing it to a varchar/nvarchar with no luck - still corrupted. thanks though!

Comment: in that case my guess is that ADODB is changing the codepage from the original data. I had to do quite a bit of trial and error before I found the best way to stop BCP doing it. It might be worth taking a document putting it in the database and back out again then comparing the original with the version from the DB using Notepad++ or similar. Gives you quite a good idea as to what is happening. This seems to indicate that by default ADO will be exporting to  Unicode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/charset-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I tried setting the charset with this `EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Charset','Windows-1252'`, but the problem persists. Not sure which charset pdf would expect.

Comment: i think it's more that the charset that was used when the document got BLOBed needs to be the same when it is exported. Have you tried doing a file compare to see where the problem is?

Comment: when I import my own file and export it, it works perfectly. the challenge is with the blobs already stored in the DB

Comment: in that case your best bet is to try to work out which characters in the file are causing it to be corrupt - Notepad++ is your friend.